# Sliding menu using jfeinstein10

Tags: android, fragment, slidingmenu

I am using [jfeinstein10](https://github.com/jfeinstein10/SlidingMenu) library and sample project. I want to show some menu option in left sliding menu and also some other option menu in the right sliding menu. But i am not able to do that . Here is the code :
package com.slidingmenu.example;

```
public class LeftAndRightActivity extends BaseActivity {

    public LeftAndRightActivity() {
        super(R.string.left_and_right);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        getSlidingMenu().setMode(SlidingMenu.LEFT_RIGHT);
        getSlidingMenu().setTouchModeAbove(SlidingMenu.TOUCHMODE_FULLSCREEN);

        setContentView(R.layout.content_frame);
        getSupportFragmentManager()
        .beginTransaction()
        .replace(R.id.content_frame, new SampleFragment())
        .commit();

        getSlidingMenu().setSecondaryMenu(R.layout.menu_frame_two);
        getSlidingMenu().setSecondaryShadowDrawable(R.drawable.shadowright);
        getSupportFragmentManager()
        .beginTransaction()
        .replace(R.id.menu_frame_two, new SampleFragment())
        .commit();
    }

}
```

Here it is what i have set in the onCreate :

```
getSlidingMenu().setMode(SlidingMenu.LEFT_RIGHT);
        getSlidingMenu().setTouchModeAbove(SlidingMenu.TOUCHMODE_FULLSCREEN);

        setContentView(R.layout.content_frame);

        getSupportFragmentManager()
        .beginTransaction()
        .replace(R.id.content_frame, new SampleListFragment())
        .commit();


        getSlidingMenu().setMenu(R.layout.menu_frame_two);
        getSlidingMenu().setShadowDrawable(R.drawable.shadowright);
        getSupportFragmentManager()
        .beginTransaction()
        .replace(R.id.menu_frame_two, new SampleListFragment2())
        .commit();

        getSlidingMenu().setSecondaryMenu(R.layout.menu_frame_two);
        getSlidingMenu().setSecondaryShadowDrawable(R.drawable.shadowright);
        getSupportFragmentManager()
        .beginTransaction()
        .replace(R.id.menu_frame_two, new SampleListFragment2())
        .commit();
```

here whenever i use this my program get crashed.And here is my logcat :

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.slidingmenu.example/com.slidingmenu.example.LeftAndRightActivity}: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No view found for id 0x7f05003c for fragment Fragment{41260b30 #0 id=0x7f05003c}
```

Comment: You have to build your own menu structure inside SampleFragment

Comment: What are you not able to do? what happens... or what does not work?

Comment: how to set the menu item/ fragemnt for the left menu?